# How can I take the 2nd max from a Tensorflow tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Right now, my function uses argmax:

```
 p = tf.stop_gradient(tf.argmax(prev, 1))
```

I have tried using the following, but the dimn are incompatible:

```
 p = tf.stop_gradient(tf.nn.top_k(prev, 2)[1])

 raise ValueError("Linear is expecting 2D arguments: %s" % str(shapes))
 ValueError: Linear is expecting 2D arguments: [[None, 2, 1024], [None, 1024]]
```

My TF version might be 0.5, which is why top_k only has 2 args.

Answer (score 6):

Check the documentation for tf.nn.top_k(). The function returns values and indices. So something like below should work.

```
values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(prev,2)
p = tf.stop_gradient(indices[1])
```

Comment: ValueError: Shape TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(2)]) must have rank 1

Comment: To clarify, the error is thrown by doing:   x = indices[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
p = tf.stop_gradient(indices[1])
output tf.Tensor(962, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

But I need output in this form:

```
tf.Tensor([962], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer is not clear, please add an explanation to your code. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for details on how to answer